# Split cell value into two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, split

In Column A I have values as follows:

```
A1: 1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;               
A2: 1234567890;1234567890          
A3: 1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;
```

Now I want to store value after 33rd character or third semi-colon into the separate B column.

Result:

### Column A (Result should be)

```
A1: 1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;  
A2: 1234567890;1234567890  
A3: 1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;
```

### Column B (Result should be)

```
A1: 1234567890;1234567890;1234567890;        
A2:          
A3:
```

Note In Column B A2 & A3 are blank as they are less than 33 character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Text_to_column` tool in DATA tab of the excel sheet..
When the dialog box appears

- select the `Fixed Width` radio button and click next
- Then select the `range` you want to split..
- Then next and Finish..

You will get the required output..